# Mounting error on centos 7

Tags: centos, centos7, mount

I am trying to mount a volume on my centos 7 digital ocean server. When I try to do a mount -a I get this error.

```
mount: /dev/sda: can't read superblock
```

I can see the volume in /dev/disk/by-id/ with the name of scsi-0DO_Volume_volume-nyc1-01 and when I check the symbolic link it looks fine.

```
file /dev/disk/by-id/*
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0DO_Volume_volume-nyc1-01: symbolic link to `../../sda'
```

I have tried to use the mount script with no luck.

```
mount -o discard,defaults /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0DO_Volume_volume-nyc1-01 /mnt/volume-nyc1-01;
```

I am a newbie and just trying to work out whether its the volume that is corrupted or whether I am doing something incorrect.

I will add that the mount was working perfectly until the digital ocean server migration but just want to ensure that I am doing the correct thing.

Comment: Check `dmesg` output.

Comment: Thanks! you saved me a ton of wasted time.

[    3.989676] EXT4-fs (sda): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    3.992554] EXT4-fs (sda): write access will be enabled during recovery